# List all attributes of a subscriber list

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, php

I am working with the marketing cloud web service API and I am trying to locate a method that returns a list with all attributes of a subscriber list (like: FirstName, LastName, Gender, and so on)

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

By retrieving all of the lists a subscriber is on, you can understand which email sends a subscriber receives and whether that subscriber should be removed from these lists.You can use this in your Subscription Center to show to which lists an individual subscriber is subscribed.

Go to this link:-https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-all-lists-a-subscriber-is-on.html